# PHP not replacing a line with special characters

Tags: php

I have written a module for a PHP IRC bot which uses a database for saving which nicks are "linked" to a Wikipedia account. To do this, I have the following code:

```
$pudb_wnas = file('cache.ucb');
foreach ($pudb_wnas as $lineNumber => $line) {
    if (preg_match("/" . p_chars($ex[4]) . "~!/i", $line) != false) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if ($found) {
    echo "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!FOUND!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n";
    $lines = file('cache.ucb', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $wnas_bu = $lines[$lineNumber];                                                                                                                                            
    $lines[$lineNumber] = trim($wnas_bu) . "~!" . $mask[0];                                                                                                                    
    file_put_contents('cache.ucb', implode("\n", $lines));                                                                                                                     
} else {
    $udb_wnas = fopen("cache.ucb", "a+");
    fwrite($udb_wnas, "\n" . p_chars($ex[4]) . "~!" . $mask[0]);
    fclose($udb_wnas);
}
```

The `p_chars` function, alongside with `dp_chars`, is a custom function to add or remove backslashes to some special characters:

```
function p_chars( $text ) {
    $m_text = str_replace("(", "\(", $text);
    $m_text = str_replace(")", "\)", $m_text);
    return $m_text;
}

// Función para descodificar p_chars
function dp_chars( $text ) {
    $m_text = str_replace("\(", "(", $text);
    $m_text = str_replace("\)", ")", $m_text);
    return $m_text;
}
```

The cache.ucb file (which is really nas.udb, but that's another story) contents are located [here](https://github.com/unrar/unbot/blob/master/nas.udb). You can also see the full code [here](https://github.com/unrar/unbot/blob/master/sybil.php).

The variable $ex[4], in this context, means the argument passed to the %nas command, which is used from IRC like this: `%nas Test`.

When you call the command, it searches on the [cache.ucb](https://github.com/unrar/unbot/blob/master/nas.udb) file for a line starting with `$ex[4]."~!"`. I use `~!` as a separator. For example, if the command arguments were `%nas Testing`, it'd search for `Testing~!`. If it founds the line, it replaces it with itself **plus** `"~!".$mask[0]`. `$mask[0]` is the nickname of the user who called the command.

If it doesn't find the line, it'll add a new one following this structure: `$ex[4]~!$mask[0]`. So, as an example, if Bousie did `%nas Testing`, it would search for `Testing~!`. Assuming the line was `Testing~!Test`, it would replace it with `Testing~!Test~!Bousie`. Else, it'd add the line `Testing~!Bousie`.

The problem is that, if Bousie did `%nas UnRar`, it'd work properly. But if Bousie did `%nas I(L)Verano`, it'd add a new line. But there's already the I(L)Verano line. Note that it **should** convert the `I(L)Verano` argument to `I\(L\)Verano` before sarching it, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong on this code.

You'd really help me telling me what I'm doing wrong. Oh, and I tried with lots of codes I saw here, I tried mixing them and... Perhaps the problem is on the p_chars and dp_chars functions? I can't see it, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is

```
$file = "cache.ucb";
$ex[4] = "I\(L\)Verano";
$nick = "Bousie";
$pudb_wnas = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

var_dump($pudb_wnas); // before
foreach ( $pudb_wnas as $k => &$line ) {
    preg_match(sprintf("/^%s~/", preg_quote($ex[4])), $line) and $line = sprintf("%s~!%s", $line, $nick);
}
var_dump($pudb_wnas); // after
file_put_contents($file, implode(PHP_EOL, $pudb_wnas));
```

Before

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'UnRar~!Catbuntu' (length=15)
  1 => string 'MistrX~!MRX' (length=11)
  2 => string 'I\(L\)Verano~!ILVerano' (length=22)
  3 => &string '-jem-~!jem-' (length=11)
```

After

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'UnRar~!Catbuntu' (length=15)
  1 => string 'MistrX~!MRX' (length=11)
  2 => string 'I\(L\)Verano~!ILVerano~!Bousie' (length=30)  // works perfectly 
  3 => &string '-jem-~!jem-' (length=11)
```

Comment: Thankyou, thankyou, thankyou! It works perfectly. You can see how I adapted it on my code here: https://github.com/unrar/unbot/blob/master/sybil.php Thanks again! Although, I have a question: why `... as $k => &$line`? Why is it &$line? Thanks again, and again!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php .. talks about all the symbols